# Sms delivery fail, but money still charged

Tags: sms-gateway

Can any body explain why sms gateways take money on fail delivery?
Yes i understand that sometimes confirm that sms was delivered its hard but even if services says cant deliver it still take money.
Because then they are not loosing money and why to hurry up? I used when when they answered to me after one week. After one week they answered why sms was not delivered.

As part of question would be how to deal with that because now i see only one option to use two different services and track if user try to send sms twice and account is not confirmed then use other service as previous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way these services work is that they incur cost on every SMS sent, even if not delivered. Do note that in most of the cases, this is not the telecom provider's cost, as that is pretty minimal because of the bulk purchases these services do. It is more of the cost of their entire infrastructure etc. in sending out that SMS.

To put it in perspective, take case of email service providers. They also charge based on number of emails sent, irrespective of whether the emails are actually delivered or not.

And to minimize this cost, you need to try a few services to see which one has the best data bank of numbers that have least non-delivery rate.